# При анимации задвигания нижней панели остается белое место

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-layout, android-animation

Посмотрите на разметку

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_bg"/>

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swiper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/audio_list"/>

            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/music_sheet"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/music_panel"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/sheet_door"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fab"
    app:backgroundTint="#527dad"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.lovemusic.bestmusiclife.FABScrollBehavior"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/container_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Я ловлю события скролла в `FloatingActionButton.Behavior`. При скролле вниз скрываю `FAB` затем анимирую задвижение панели (include - music_panel). При скролле вверх все работает отлично, а вот при скролле вниз анимация задвижения панели оставляет за собой белое место, когда анимация завершается, оно исчезает и список становится видно. В конце анимации я ставлю `View.GONE` панели. Как анимировать закрытие панели, чтобы белого места не было, а сразу было видно список?

Я думаю так. Так как панель и `FrameLayout` расположены в `LinearLayout`, то во время анимации `FrameLayout` не знает, что появилось место. А в конце анимации так как панель скрывается.(`View.GONE`) он занимает место панели. Если ставить `View.GONE` перед началом анимации то анимации не будет. Как быть?

Comment: Заменил `LinearLayout` на `RelativeLayout` - безрезультатно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Отлов скролла

```
public abstract class zScrollController extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    private int lastHold, allScroll;
    private boolean upTrackingBlocked, downTrackingBlocked;

    @Override
    public final void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        allScroll += dy;
        if (allScroll > lastHold + getThreshold()) {
            lastHold = allScroll;
            if (!downTrackingBlocked){
                downTrackingBlocked = true;
                upTrackingBlocked = false;
                onDownScrolled();
            }
        } else if (allScroll < lastHold - getThreshold()) {
            lastHold = allScroll;
            if (!upTrackingBlocked){
                upTrackingBlocked = true;
                downTrackingBlocked = false;
                onUpScrolled();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    /**
     * Default threshold for scrolling, value in pixels
     * */
    public static final int DEFAULT_THRESHOLD = 30;

    /**
     * Big threshold for scrolling, value in pixels
     * */
    public static final int BIG_THRESHOLD = 50;

    /**
     * Very big threshold for scrolling, value in pixels
     * */
    public static final int VERY_BIG_THRESHOLD = 100;

    /**
     * Threshold for scrolling. By default have 30 px
     * */
    public int getThreshold() {
        return DEFAULT_THRESHOLD;
    }

    public abstract void onUpScrolled();
    public abstract void onDownScrolled();
}
```

### Анимирование панели (родительский компонент - FrameLayout)

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = panel.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int pahelHeight = panel.getHeight();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new zScrollController(){
            @Override
            public void onUpScrolled(){
                if (!fab.isShown()) fab.show();
                ViewCompat.animate(panel)/*тут ваша анимация*/
                    .withEndAction(() -> recyclerView.setPadding(
                        recyclerView.getPaddingLeft(),
                        recyclerView.getPaddingTop(),
                        recyclerView.getPaddingRight(),
                        panelHeight
                    )
                );
            }
            @Override
            public void onDownScrolled(){
                if (fab.isShown()) fab.hide();
                ViewCompat.animate(panel)/*тут ваша анимация*/
                    .withStartAction(() -> recyclerView.setPadding(
                        recyclerView.getPaddingLeft(),
                        recyclerView.getPaddingTop(),
                        recyclerView.getPaddingRight(),
                        0
                    )
                );
            }
            @Override
            public int getThreshold() {
                return DEFAULT_THRESHOLD; //optional
            }
        });
        ViewTreeObserver observer = panel.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Не помогло. Белое место выше панели вообще

Comment: Спасибо, получилось